# How to use regular expression while searching in HashSet

Tags: java, regex, set

I am writing a Java program in which I need to search a particular word from a Set. The word that has to be searched is something like ("wo.d") where '.' can be replaced by any other alphabet. I am using regex to match such type of word cases.

This is what I have so far

```
HashSet<String> words = new HashSet<String>();//this set is already populated
String word = "t.st";
if(word.contains(".")){
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(word);
    Matcher m;
    boolean match = false;
    for(String setWord : words){
        m = p.matcher(setWord);
        if(m.matches())
            match = true;
    }
    if(match)
        System.out.println("Its a match");
    else
        System.out.println("Its not a match");
}
else{
    System.out.println("The word does not contain regex do other stuff");
}
```

The code above works but is not efficient because it is being called many times in a second. So it produces a lag in the program.

Comment: Is there any chance of multiple match  in that set ?

Comment: What do you mean by multiple match? if I am using a regex searching for a word 'w.od' it would give multiple matches for ex 'word & wood'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to stop iterating as soon as you get a match, so assuming that you use `Java 8`, your `for` loop could be rewritten efficiently as next:

```
boolean match = words.stream().anyMatch(w -> p.matcher(w).matches());
```

You could also parallelize the research using `parallelStream()` instead of `stream()` especially if your `Set` has a lot of words.

If you don't use `Java 7`, it could still be done using [`FluentIterable`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html) from [**Google Guava**](https://github.com/google/guava) but without the ability to parallelize the research unfortunately.

```
boolean match = FluentIterable.from(words).anyMatch(
    new Predicate<String>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(@Nullable final String w) {
            return p.matcher(w).matches();
        }
    }
);
```

But in your case, I don't believe that using `FluentIterable` can be more interesting than simply adding a `break` when you get a match, as it will still be easier to read and maintain

```
if (p.matcher(setWord).matches()) {
    match = true;
    break;
}
```

So, if you really need to use a **regular expression** and you cannot use `Java 8`, your best option is to use `break` as described above, there is no magic trick to consider.

---

Assuming that you will **only have one character to replace**, it could be done using [`startsWith(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith-java.lang.String-) and [`endsWith(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith-java.lang.String-) which will always be **much faster than a regular expression**. Something like this:

```
// Your words should be in a TreeSet to be already sorted alphabetically 
// in order to get a match as fast as possible
Set<String> words = new TreeSet<String>(); //this set is already populated
int index = word.indexOf('.');
if (index != -1) {
    String prefix = word.substring(0, index);
    String suffix = word.substring(index + 1);
    boolean match = false;
    for (String setWord : words){
        // From the fastest to the slowest thing to check 
        // to get the best possible performances
        if (setWord.length() == word.length() 
            && setWord.startsWith(prefix) 
            && setWord.endsWith(suffix)) {
            match = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(match)
        System.out.println("Its a match");
    else
        System.out.println("Its not a match");
}
else {
    System.out.println("The word does not contain regex do other stuff");
}
```

Comment: `words.stream().anyMatch(w -> p.matcher(w).matches())`.

Comment: this will work, but unfortunately I am still working with Java 7.

Comment: You will only have one character to replace anywhere in the word with any character or it could be more complex?

Comment: No, just one character.

Comment: so check the second part of my answer, you won't be able to get something faster IMO

Answer (score 2):

Use TreeSet instead of HashSet.  And test for sub range of the set.

```
TreeSet<String> words = new TreeSet<>();// this set is already populated
String word = "t.st";
if (word.contains(".")) {
    String from = word.replaceFirst("\\..*", "");
    String to = from + '\uffff';
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(word);
    Matcher m;
    boolean match = false;
    for (String setWord : words.subSet(from, to)) {
        m = p.matcher(setWord);
        if (m.matches()) {
            match = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (match)
        System.out.println("Its a match");
    else
        System.out.println("Its not a match");
} else {
    System.out.println("The word does not contain regex do other stuff");
}
```

In this case `words.subSet(from, to)` contains only the words start with "t".

Answer (score 0):

Just break out of loop to stop further regex matching of your `HashSet` as soon as you get a match:

```
if(m.matches()) {
   match = true;
   break;
}
```

**Full Code:**

```
HashSet<String> words = new HashSet<String>();//this set is already populated
String word = "t.st";
if(word.contains(".")){
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(word);
    Matcher m;
    boolean match = false;
    for(String setWord : words){
        m = p.matcher(setWord);
        if(m.matches()) {
            match = true;
            break:
        }
    }
    if(match)
        System.out.println("Its a match");
    else
        System.out.println("Its not a match");
}
else{
    System.out.println("The word does not contain regex do other stuff");
}
```

Comment: I have tried using break, it does improve the searching speed. But i was looking for a better solution than what I wrote.

Comment: What is size of your set? Just matching `t.st` for thousands of items in set shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: It's close to 100,000

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem with this approach as regex is very simple.

Comment: Yes, it won't be a problem if I were dealing with just the regex and set. But I am using this in a game, and it slows it down.

Answer (score 0):

Use original matching method like this.

```
static boolean match(String wild, String s) {
    int len = wild.length();
    if (len != s.length())
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        char w = wild.charAt(i);
        if (w == '.')
            continue;
        else if (w != s.charAt(i))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and

```
HashSet<String> words = new HashSet<>();// this set is already populated
String word = "t.st";
boolean match = false;
if (word.contains(".")) {
    for (String setWord : words) {
        if (match(word, setWord)) {
            match = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (match)
        System.out.println("Its a match");
    else
        System.out.println("Its not a match");
} else {
    System.out.println("The word does not contain regex do other stuff");
}
```